# RH 7 and AD integration - Realm missing information

Tags: linux, active-directory, redhat

I have a hopefully odd one.

I am trying my hand at getting our new RH 7 servers to integrate with our AD. This is a RH 7.1 server fully patched but does have some security settings set (nothing major, just standard STIG's). When I run 'realm discover' I don't see all the information.

```
[root@$SERVERNAME$]# realm discover $DOMAIN$
$DOMAIN$
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: $DOMAIN$
  domain-name: $DOMAIN$
  configured: no
[root@$SERVERNAME$]#
```

I installed sssd but haven't configured it at all yet. All the documents I keep running across seem to be about 5 steps above where I'm starting. This is my current hurdle and if I can get past it, I might be able to make some traction. Does anyone know why I'm not seeing the server or client software listed? I'm pretty sure I have all the dependencies. Although I can't just join the domain either.

Update:
I've made progress. Figured out my permission issue with the sssd.conf file, corrected a mistake in krb5.conf and installed my NIS and UNIX properties on my DC's. I think I have to go through and check my files again because now I'm getting some information but of course it's case sensitive. I think I have mis-matches all over. I don't like the required software on here though because I verified that all those packages are installed.

```
[root@$SERVERNAME$]# realm -v discover $domain$
 * Resolving: _ldap._tcp.$domain$
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: xxx.xxx.101.22
 * Performing LDAP DSE lookup on: xxx.xxx.105.22
 * Successfully discovered: $DOMAIN$
$DOMAIN$
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: $DOMAIN$
  domain-name: $DOMAIN$
  configured: no
  server-software: active-directory
  client-software: sssd
  required-package: oddjob
  required-package: oddjob-mkhomedir
  required-package: sssd
  required-package: adcli
  required-package: samba-common
$domain$
  type: kerberos
  realm-name: $DOMAIN$
  domain-name: $domain$
  configured: no
[root@$SERVERNAME$]#
```

Thank you

Peace

Comment: Do you mean RHEL 7.2, do you have EUS, or is your system not actually up to date?

Comment: Try throwing the same command with the -v option as well as maybe a -u option for user authentication

Comment: Sorry. It is 7.2. I've been staring at this thing far too long.

Comment: As to the options, I do get something new to look into. With the verbose option I can see that the discovery is timing out after 15 seconds. I might have my port wrong. It's something to look into at least instead of just sitting here scratching my head.